# Reseting Identity value in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a column with Identity property with 10 records now I had truncated the table but the identity number is stil incrementing from 10 . I need to reset the identity number from 1 again. How to perform this in SQL SERVER 2008

Comment: Is identity set to start from 10? However, if there is no data at the moment, why don't you drop and re-create the table?

Answer (score 0):

Use `DBCC CHECKIDENT` with RESEED.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax to reset identity column:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT(<table_name>, RESEED, value)
```